# MS Access -> Excel connection without deleting the old rows

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I have a database of running projects in MS Access, which I would like to regularly import into Excel sheet. However, once project is done it is removed from Access database (and of course from Excel after refreshing. Is there any way to preserve the existing rows in Excel sheet? I want only adding new rows into Excel spreadsheet but no deleting of the old finished rows - projects.

Comment: Why would you delete data? Why not just leave the project in Access?

Answer (score 0):

So, you are importing Access data into Excel.  Easy.  Try the script below, and modify it to suit your needs.

```
Sub ADOImportFromAccessTable(DBFullName As String, _
    TableName As String, TargetRange As Range)
' Example: ADOImportFromAccessTable "C:\FolderName\DataBaseName.mdb", _
    "TableName", Range("C1")
Dim cn As ADODB.Connection, rs As ADODB.Recordset, intColIndex As Integer
    Set TargetRange = TargetRange.Cells(1, 1)
    ' open the database
    Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
    cn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=" & _
        DBFullName & ";"
    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
    With rs
        ' open the recordset
        .Open TableName, cn, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic, adCmdTable 
        ' all records
        '.Open "SELECT * FROM " & TableName & _
            " WHERE [FieldName] = 'MyCriteria'", cn, , , adCmdText 
        ' filter records

        RS2WS rs, TargetRange ' write data from the recordset to the worksheet

'        ' optional approach for Excel 2000 or later (RS2WS is not necessary)
'        For intColIndex = 0 To rs.Fields.Count - 1 ' the field names
'            TargetRange.Offset(0, intColIndex).Value = rs.Fields(intColIndex).Name
'        Next
'        TargetRange.Offset(1, 0).CopyFromRecordset rs ' the recordset data

    End With
    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
    cn.Close
    Set cn = Nothing
End Sub
```